# Open ibooks programmatically with file in documents directory

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ibooks, uidocumentinteraction

Is it possible to open an .ibooks file within my documents directory automatically, without any UIDocumentInteractionController? 
Maybe by manipulating the url or something like this?

I tried opening it via shared application but it didn't work well:

```
NSString *filePath = [self.serviceMedia pathToIbook];
NSURL *url = [NSURL filePath];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

BTW: The url is valid and not nil and starting with "file://var..."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iBooks has an undocumented URL scheme of **ibooks**. This means you can launch iBooks with a URL like `[NSURL URLWithString:@"ibooks://"]`.

However, there is no documentation on how to pass a specific file to this URL. So basically, there is no documented way to do what you are asking.

Despite your requirement, **UIDocumentInteractionController** is the correct way to do this. It is the way Apple wants you to do it. Plus, using **UIDocumentInteractionController** has the benefit of letting the user decide what to do with the file.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately it is not possible otherwise. I tried it with the "ibooks" URL and sharedApplication openURL - without effort...